# How to display the y-axis labels in percentage in a column chart or bar chart in .NET Report Viewer

Tags: c#, winforms, bar-chart, column-chart

I have spent a few hours finding a solution to display the y-axis in percentage in a column chart in Microsoft Report Viewer but couldn't find any solution.

According to the graph in the screenshot, y-axis values are in actual value. I want them to be scale to % (0-100).

[image]

I am developing windows form in visual studio 2012.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can pass percentage values for Y-Axis forehand.

And if you don't want to do that, use [Stacked Bar Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456771(v=vs.100).aspx), where chart type is `StackedBar100`, something like below :

```
<Series ChartType="StackedBar100" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PointWidth=0.75, MaxPixelPointWidth=40">
    <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
</Series>
```

Comment: Thanks. 100% Stacked Bar / Column chart is an option, but, since I only have one category, there is only one column which doesn't look so nice.